# Keeping common data across sessions in flask server without reading from db for each session

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, server, google-cloud-firestore

What I am doing now is integrating flask server with Google App Engine and connecting to Firestore.

I'd like to keep the data saved in server memory. It is a data that does not need to be read (it will stay same as long as I manually change it in DB). But it is needed in almost every page. So I do not want to read it again and again for each users.

I googled for a while and figured out that session and g doesn't fit my purpose (as session will persist per user and g per request).

Is there any way that I can keep my data in server memory and not reading DB every time?

Comment: Sure, you could implement an in-memory cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use App Engine you need to know that according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed) and the scaling type you chose all your instances might be restarted at some point. Thus, the data you store in its RAM memory will be lost. Also each App Engine instance has is own memory so you can have consistency problems if your workload makes App Engine to spin several instances.

I would recommend you to use a Storage solution instead of the instance memory. You can have a look at the several options at the [Google Cloud storage services options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/storage-options#gcp-storage-services) documentation page for App Engines.